# Which plugin installed this "SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - Begin Analysis"

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I see one Jenkins instance has this step and also "MSBuild SonarQube Runner" section in the system configuration, but another doesn't. I am trying to use Jenkins and SonarQube to analyse C# projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it's only available in SonarQube plugin since v4.4:
http://www.sonarqube.org/easy-analysis-of-visual-studio-solutions-with-the-sonarqube-scanner-for-msbuild/